# Arabic text to speech on iphone

Tags: iphone, text-to-speech, arabic

is there any Arabic text to speech open source API for iphone ??
other than [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears)

Comment: I've made a Google Speech API client. I don't know whether Google supports Arabic but you may have it a go (much simpler to use than OpenEars): https://github.com/H2CO3/libsprec

Comment: i tried OpenEars and it dosen't support arabic :(
did u know how i can make Arabic language model ??

Comment: I'm not sure if that's allowed in SO. But we have a language model and an API for Quran. Does that work for you? http://eqratech.com

Answer (score 1):

Fist off, are you looking for text to speech or speech recognition?  You said "text to speech recognition" in your title.  As far as open source, I haven't seen anything that is decent yet.  Try CMU, but you are probably going to need to train your own acoustic models with data - not an easy task.

iSpeech has Arabic text to speech (TTS) in their free SDKs.  https://www.ispeech.org/developers
I think they have Arabic speech recognition, but I couldn't find it in the documentation... You could always ask.

Google is an option, but who knows when they will start charging $20 per million characters like they do with their Translate API now.

Comment: i mismatch typing Q,i mean TTS i tried open ears and it dosen't support Arabic :(
i tried iSpeech and it's not free !!!

Comment: An anonymous user has said: *"Sorry - not exactly free. It looks like iSpeech charges for removing their branding, but is free with their branding/popup. I never noticed since I used their speech recognition."*

Comment: OpenEars developer here -- just wanted to mention that the asker already tried the CMU packages when they tried OpenEars.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
       let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: yourtext)
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "ar_SA")
        utterance.rate = 0.4

        let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```